# How to handle transformation of GenericRecords with Flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have an application which reads from different Kafka topics. These topics could have records with varying schema. But they are all using avro

I want my application to be agnostic of which avro schema it is. So I am deserializing the data read from Kafka as `GenericRecord`. However, flink is not good at serializing `GenericRecord` while sending it across operators

So what I do is during the Kafka deserialization part, I deserialize the data to GenericRecord, extract some expected ids out of them and serialize the `GenericRecord` back to byte array and populate a custom POJO with that byte array as well as the schema information in string format. I am using a stream of this POJO in all my subsequent operators.

This way, my application is agnostic of which avro schema it is. However, lets say if I want to transform the initial `GenericRecord` to something else, like lets say a compact version and serialize this compact version of data and use it in the POJO, what is the best way to achieve this?

I can always do it at the deserializer part where I can convert it to a different GenericRecord. But is it possible to do it afterwards like once I get `DataStream<GenericRecord>`? Flink complains about not being able to serialize `GenericRecord`. So if I try to transform this to another `DataStream<GenericRecord>` with simpler data and then transform it to `DataStream<POJO>` will it work?

While transforming from one `DataStream<GenericRecord>` to another `DataStream<GenericRecord>`, flink does have to serialize the data. And with `GenericRecord`, that could have dynamic schema, it will not work